# iPad stuck in Guided Access

Tags: password, ipad

Hello I haven't used Guided Access in a while and I needed to use it again. I had previously set a passcode and I went to use it expecting it would ask for a new passcode, but it must've used the old one. I have no idea what the old one is and I can't get anything off. I had tried holding down Home/Lock for 10 seconds but it just seemed to start up, unlock itself and go back to the app I was on.

Guided Access was still turned on and I have no idea how to remove it.

Comment: I've figured out the passcode but I am leaving this question here and I would like it if someone answered so people will know how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

If you continue to be unable to guess the passcode by brute force attempts, you can connect the device to a computer that has synced the device and unlock things with a sync.

Also, this article shows an alternate method involving a reboot, force quit, and other manipulation of settings in a specified order. Hopefully it helps if you can't use the two "approved" methods above.

http://blog.technguide.net/2012/08/how-to-get-out-of-guided-access-on-ios6/

> 1. Hold the Lock Button
> 2. Slide the Slide To Power Off slider [If touch is disabled/you're unable to slide it, do a hard reset — hold the lock and home button for 8 seconds until the Apple Logo appears]
> 3. When your iDevices powers up, immediately exit the app that automatic open.
> 4. Go to Settings > General > Accessibility > Guided Access
> 5. Click Set Passcode
> 6. Enter new password
> 7. Reboot again.
> 8. Wait for the app to automatically open and Triple tap the home button
> 9. Enter the new password
> 10. Unlocked!